# How to make an array to unzip and give a pure text with a proper shuffle?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

```
import random

a = []

l = int(input("please enter the numbers of number that you like to add to your password")) 
for i in range(l):
    s = int(input("please enter the numbers that you like to add to your password"))
    a.append(s)
print("some selected values are -", a)

print()

b = []
m = int(input("please enter the number of alphabets that you like to have in ur password"))
for j in range(m):
     t = input("please enter the alphabets you desire to insert to your password ")
     b.append(t)
print("the alphabets that are selected are -", b)

print()

c = []
n = int(input("please enter the number of symbols that you like to have in your password"))
for k in range(n):
     u = (input("please enter the symbols you would like to have in your password"))
     c.append(u)
print("the symbols you  desired are - ", c)


d = (a, b, c)
t = tuple(zip(a, b, c))

print(d, t)
o = int(input("for how many times your password needs to be shuffled"))

for p in range(o):
      f = random.sample(d, len(d))
      g = random.sample(t, len(t))

print(f)
print(g)
```

There are no syntax errors in this code. As it is not giving a result of what I have desired I have some problems with this code.

1. The results of the code are:
   *f* = **[[1, 5, 7], ['a', 'w'], [')', '*', '%', '\', '|']]**

   *g* = **[(5, 'w', '*'), (1, 'a', ')')]**

> "My desired result wanted to be in a no bracket and no commas format"

2. From the above result, I also wanted it to be in a well shuffled result,

> If you see the above result which came as the result of my above code you can observe that only the user-created list were shuffled without the elements inside the list actually shuffled "They were not actually shuffled properly (not inter-shuffled)"

3. Some elements were also ghosted and were not properly gave the input

Please help me in clearing all of this errors and I hope you know the motive of my code and I really plead for your help.

> I really needed to clear this and I have been trying to Finish this code for the past 2 months. PLease help me in clearing this because I am a small struggling nerd of python coding

Please help mr get out of my problem so that i can continue learning.

Answer (score 0):

After you have collected the various inputs to your password, you likely want to add those lists together and simply shuffle the results.

Note, to make things slightly cleaner I also stopped casting the individual numbers to `int`. If that turns out to actually be important, we can fix that.

```
import random

a = []

l = int(input("please enter the numbers of number that you like to add to your password"))
for i in range(l):
    ## ---- Note I stopped casting to int
    s = input("please enter the numbers that you like to add to your password")
    a.append(s)
print("some selected values are -", a)

print()

b = []
m = int(input("please enter the number of alphabets that you like to have in ur password"))
for j in range(m):
     t = input("please enter the alphabets you desire to insert to your password ")
     b.append(t)
print("the alphabets that are selected are -", b)

print()

c = []
n = int(input("please enter the number of symbols that you like to have in your password"))
for k in range(n):
     u = (input("please enter the symbols you would like to have in your password"))
     c.append(u)
print("the symbols you  desired are - ", c)

## --------------
## join the 3 lists together
## --------------
d = a + b + c
print(d)
## --------------

## --------------
## shuffle the full list up
## --------------
random.shuffle(d)
print(d)
## --------------

## --------------
## print the password as a string
## if you want to keep the cast to int above then:
## print("".join(str(i) for i in d))
## --------------
print("".join(d))
## --------------
```

Comment: Hey, I want to do a super thanking to you. I really love the way you responded me and I am really grateful for your answer, the errors got cleared. May you chase and reach your dreams soon :-)